# Convexity in NMF proof

Tags: convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

I am currently studying a proof for the NMF multiplicative update rule based on generalized Kullback-Leibler divergence in the paper [Algorithms for Non-negative Matrix
Factorization](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1861-algorithms-for-non-negative-matrix-factorization.pdf), and for some reason I just can't seem to figure out how to derive equation 29 (in proof for Lemma 3).

I was thinking about using the classic version of Jensen's inequality, stating that $\varphi\Big(\frac{\sum_{a} \alpha_a x_a}{\sum_{a} \alpha_a} \Big) \leq \frac{\sum_{a} \alpha_a \varphi(x_a)}{\sum_{a} \alpha_a}$ for positive $\alpha_a$'s and $\varphi$ convex. Since the $\alpha_a$'s sum to unity, I guess the inequality can be reduced to $\varphi(\sum_{a} \alpha_a x_a) \leq \sum_{a} \alpha_a \varphi(x_a)$, and hence by letting $x_a = \frac{W_{ia} h_a}{\alpha_a}$, we obtain the inequality
\begin{align*}
\log \sum_a \alpha_a \frac{W_{ia} h_a}{\alpha_a} = \log \sum_a W_{ia} h_a \leq \sum_a \alpha_a \log \frac{W_{ia} h_a}{\alpha_a},
\end{align*}
but then multiplying with -1 the inequlity flips, which is not the case in the paper.

Any suggestions to where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the Jensen inequality (as stated) to the function $-\log$ (which is convex) instead of $\log$ (which is concave).

Comment: Thanks man. I think the "use the conexity of the log function" part confused me

Comment: @JerryT Yes it seems to be a typo from the authors.